# Why does my code always return 100% CPU load and 0 MB free ram?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, load

I want to get the CPU Load and the RAM Load (and if possible the GPU load) using C# in unity. My Code always says my CPU is at 100% Load and my RAM always has 0MB free. Why is that and how can I fix this? And if possibke how can I additionally get the GPU load?

I used several things i found on several sites and settled for a Code that didnt give me an Error and output something with little adjustments. The only problem is that i always returns 100% CPU load and 0MB Free ram. I checked in the Task Manager and the Values where ~20% and 2.4 GB Free.
Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class LoadMeasure : MonoBehaviour {
    
    //PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
    //PerformanceCounter ramCounter;
    System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
    System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter ramCounter;
    
    
    void Start() {
        System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists("PerformanceCounter");
        
        cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
    
        cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
        cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
        cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";
    
        ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
    }
    
    void Update(){
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("> cpu: "+getCurrentCpuUsage()+"; >ram: "+getAvailableRAM());
        
    }

    public string getCurrentCpuUsage(){
                return cpuCounter.NextValue()+"%";
    }

    public string getAvailableRAM(){
                return ramCounter.NextValue()+"MB";
    } 
}
```

Comment: This might be relevant (from Unity forum): [PerformanceCounters return 0MB RAM and %100 CPU in Unity](https://discussions.unity.com/t/performancecounters-return-0mb-ram-and-100-cpu-in-unity/221779).

Answer (score -1):

It looks like there are a couple of issues in your code that might be causing the incorrect values. Let's go through them and make the necessary corrections:

**1. Initialization of Performance Counters:**
The **PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists("PerformanceCounter")**; line does not serve any purpose, and it doesn't create an instance of the counter category. You should remove it.

**2. Sampling Rate:**
Performance counters need some time to collect accurate data. In your current implementation, you are calling **NextValue()** immediately after initializing the counters. This may result in inaccurate readings. You should introduce a delay before calling **NextValue()**.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

public class LoadMeasure : MonoBehaviour
{
private PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
private PerformanceCounter ramCounter;

void Start()
{
    cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
    ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
}

void Update()
{
    // Introduce a delay before sampling again
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("> cpu: " + getCurrentCpuUsage() + "; >ram: " + getAvailableRAM());
}

public string getCurrentCpuUsage()
{
    // Call NextValue twice to get a valid reading
    cpuCounter.NextValue();
    return cpuCounter.NextValue() + "%";
}

public string getAvailableRAM()
{
    return ramCounter.NextValue() + "MB";
}
}
```

This code introduces a delay of 1000 milliseconds (1 second) before logging the CPU and RAM usage. Additionally, calling NextValue() twice for the CPU counter helps to get a more accurate reading.

Keep in mind that measuring CPU usage accurately in Unity might be challenging due to the way Unity works and the multi-threaded nature of modern processors. The values might not be as precise as you expect, and you should use dedicated profiling tools for more accurate results.

Comment: Your entire point 2 is wrong. OP is not calling the `NextValue` immediately but rather once a frame. `Update` is called once every frame in Unity .. adding a forced freeze of a second (or any value) here will freeze the entire Unity application and Editor and force it to run with maximum 1 frame per second